# Tabhost Renders strangely in CM7 and Tablets? GUI bug

Tags: android, android-layout

For pretty much all phones, my app renders correctly: tabs located near the top.

However, for phones with CyanogenMod or tablets the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, half of the app is cutoff/displaced as below.

The GUI bug:

[image: http://imgur.com/VJoTd.png]

What it looks like on most devices:

https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.Wahoo/ss-480-0-3

Here is the main XML layout code...(pretty standard, I thought):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tab1"></LinearLayout>


            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

activity which you have set for second tab does it contain scrollview & also have u set the scrollview height is wrap_content if yes then set to fill_parent.